# Dimensional regularization yields finite result for loop integral in 3d $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, dimensional-regularization

As an exercise I wanted to compute the mass renormalization in 3d $\phi^4$ theory (1-loop).

At 1-loop the field requires no renormalization (as in the 4d case) and the mass renormalization is completely determined by the tadpole diagram. If we define
$m_0^2 = m^2Z_m$, where $m_0$ is the bare mass and $m$ the renormalized one we would expect
$$Z_m = 1 - \frac{\lambda}{2m^2}\int\frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{q^2 + m^2}$$
after Wick rotation to Euclidean momenta. As in the 4d case I tried to solve this integral by using dimensional regularization and the master integral:
$$\int\frac{d^dq}{(2\pi)^d}\frac{1}{(q^2 + m^2)^n} = \frac{\Gamma(n-\frac{d}{2})}{(4\pi)^{d/2} \cdot \Gamma(n)\cdot (m^2)^{n-{\frac{d}{2}}}}$$
In this case we have $n = 1$ and $d = 3-2\varepsilon$. By plugging into the expression above we should get

\begin{align}
Z_m &= 1 - \frac{\lambda}{2m^2}\cdot \eta^{3-d}\cdot \frac{1}{(4\pi)^{d/2}} \cdot 
\Gamma(1-\frac{d}{2})\cdot \frac{1}{(m^2)^{1 - \frac{d}{2}}} = 
1 - \frac{\lambda}{2m^2}\cdot \eta^{2\varepsilon}\cdot \frac{1}{(4\pi)^{3/2 - \varepsilon}} \cdot 
\Gamma(-\frac{1}{2} + \varepsilon)\cdot \frac{1}{(m^2)^{\varepsilon-\frac{1}{2}}} \\
&= 1 - \frac{\lambda}{2m^2(4\pi)^{3/2}}\cdot \eta^{2\varepsilon}\cdot (4\pi)^\varepsilon \cdot 
\Gamma(-\frac{1}{2} + \varepsilon)\cdot \frac{m}{(m^2)^{\varepsilon} 
} =
1 - \frac{\lambda}{2m(4\pi)^{3/2}}\cdot (4\pi)^\varepsilon \cdot 
\Gamma(-\frac{1}{2} + \varepsilon)\cdot \left(\frac{\eta^2}{m^2}\right)^{\varepsilon}
\end{align}

where the scale $\eta$ with momentum dimension $[\eta] = 1$ was introduced to maintain the total momentum dimension of the integral. Now the next step is to expand the expression in epsilon which yields

$$Z_m = 1 - \frac{\lambda}{2m(4\pi)^{3/2}}\cdot (1 + \ln(4\pi)\varepsilon) \cdot 
(-2\sqrt{\pi} + C \varepsilon) \cdot (1 + \ln\left(\frac{\eta^2}{m^2}\right)\varepsilon) + O(\varepsilon^2)$$

Where I used $\Gamma(\varepsilon - \frac{1}{2}) \approx -2\sqrt{\pi} + C \varepsilon$
with some, here irrelevant, constant $C$ (I got this expansion from Wolfram Alpha).
The last expression already encapsulates my issue: As there is no $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ term in the expansion of the Gamma function, which is different for $d=4$, I can take the $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}$ limit und obtain a finite result. How can this be if I started with an integral that should diverge in the UV? Why does dimensional regularization yield a finite result?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/576887/2451